# NVM is not detecting node version || nvm use command is not working || Liferay DXP Theme Generator issue

Tags: node.js, liferay, nvm, liferay-dxp

NVM is not detecting installed node version,
Trying to change node version from 14.0 to 12.22.2.

```
nvm use 12.22.2
```

Above command is not working. It showing

> node V12.22.2(64 bit) is not installed.

Answer (score 2):

For this, the simple solution is you need to use NVM itself to download node.

So you can try like below,

Open CMD with Administrator rights, and execute below steps.

```
nvm install 12.22.2
```

Now execute `nvm list`

You will find the 12.22.2 as result.

Now execute `nvm use 12.22.2`

It will give message that NVM is now using node version 12.22.2.

That's it.!